# Set a foreign key to nullable in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-8

Assume I have a the tables `users` and `persons`. An entry in `persons` can have a user id or not. So a person can have a user, but this is optional.

This means that the foreign key in `persons` needs to be nullable.

This is my database migration:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->nulleable()->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->nulleable()->references('id')->on('users');
```

Sadly, when I check the database columns it says, that the field is not nullable

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id    | bigint unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How can I set the foreign key to nullable? I have tried various combinations I found online, but nothing works.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Use ```$table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained();``` instead of your two lines.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to repeat nullable (not nulleable) to the second ligne,
try this :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```